# Passing a row selection string into data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to select rows in a data.table based on a variable set elsewhere and I am missing some key point of syntax.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT

#this works as expected and does what I want
DT[y<3 & v >3] 
#but how do I pass my selection criteria in?
a1<-"y<3 & v>3"
a2<-quote(y<3 & v>3)
#so that one of these works?
DT[a1] #error
DT[a2] #error
DT[eval(a1)] #error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...One last test would have done it...

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT

#this works as expected and does what I want
DT[y<3 & v >3] 
#but how do I pass my selection criteria in?
a1<-"y<3 & v>3"
a2<-quote(y<3 & v>3)
#so that one of these works?
DT[a1] #error
DT[a2] #error
DT[eval(a1)] #error

DT[eval(a2)] #works
```

Comment: If you have a `character` (like `a1`), you can also try `DT[eval(parse(text=a1))]`